# Difference in pipe and file redirection - BASH

Tags: bash, shell, redirect

**Redirection** is used to redirect stdout/stdin/stderr! 
Ex: `ls > log.txt.`

**Pipes** are used to give the output of a command as input to another command. 
Ex:  `ls | grep file.txt`

Why exactly are these two operators doing the same thing?

Why not just write `ls > grep` to pass the output through, isn't this just a kind of redirection also?

I realize Linux is "Do one thing and do it well", so there has to be more of a logical reason that I'm missing.

Comment: sending output to a file vs sending output as input to a command are not really the same thing

Comment: What if you wanted a file named `grep`? Now you would need to use `./grep` for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *do* need a differentiating syntax feature - and using `>` vs. `|` will do just fine.

If you used `>` in *both* scenarios, how would you know whether

```
ls > grep
```

is trying to write to a *file* named `grep` or send input to the `grep` *command*?

<sup>`grep` is perhaps not the best example, as you may then be tempted to disambiguate by the presence of `grep`'s mandatory arguments; however, (optionally) argument-less commands do exist, such as `column`.

[that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy) offers another example in the comments: `test` may refer to a test *output file* or to the argument-less invocation of the [standard `test` *command*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).</sup>

---

Another way of looking at it:

Your suggestion is essentially to use `>` as a generic send-output-somewhere operator, irrespective of the type of target (file vs. command).

However, that only *shifts* the need for disambiguation, and then you have to disambiguate when specifying the *target* - is it a file to output to or a command to run?

Given that the shell also has an *implicit* disambiguation feature when it comes to the *first* token of a simple command - `foo [...]` only ever invokes a *command* - differentiating at the level of the *operator* - `>` for outputting to files, `|` for sending to commands - is the sensible choice.

Comment: You could still use `ls > ./grep`... until it also is a program ; ok I give up ;)

Comment: @Aaron: What _specific_ syntax is used to disambiguate commands from filenames is ultimately irrelevant - _the point is that you do need disambiguation_, which  `>` vs. `|` does provide - and has done so for decades.

Comment: A good example might be `mycommand > test` which is a fair name for a test file and might also mean to run the command `test` (which happens to work without arguments)

Comment: @thatotherguy: Good point; I eventually came with example `column`, but I've added your example to the answer too.

Comment: @thatotherguy: Ah, I missed that - fixed (for the record: `test` without arguments conceptually tests the empty string, which is considered falsy, and therefore sets the exit code to `1`).

Answer (score 3):

This would actually make `>` do *two* things, open a file or run a new program, depending on what the operand is. (Ignoring the ambiguity when the argument is the name of an executable file: do we overwrite it or run it?)

---

`bash` and some other shells provide additional syntax (process substitution) that does technically replace the *need* for `|`, although not in a way that you would choose to use it over a pipe. For instance, you can write

```
ls > >(grep regex)
```

`>(...)` is treated as the "name" of a file (in fact, you can run `echo >(true)` to see what that file name is), whose contents are provided to the enclosed command as input. So now, instead of a single operator `|` that handles connecting output from A to the input of B, you have one operator `>` to redirect output, and another operator to redirect input.

It's also symmetrical:

```
grep regex < <(ls)
# or grep regex <(ls), since grep can read from standard input or a named file
```

`<(...)` is the "name" of an input file whose contents come from the output of the enclosed command.

The benefit of process substitution (and their underlying basis, named pipes) is when you want one process to write to many processes:

```
command1 | tee >(command2) >(command3) >(command4)
```

or for one process to read from many processes:

```
diff <(command1) <(command2)
```

Comment: ++ for the info about process substitutions. Syntactically, it again comes down to  simple-command syntax:  `|`, `>(...)` and `<(...)` expect a _command_, and the first token of a (simple) command is unambiguously a _command name_.

Comment: Permit me this tangent: as for what other shells support process substitution: both `zsh` and `ksh` accept the _syntax_; however, while the output of `echo foo > >(cat)` is `foo`, as expected, in `bash` and `zsh`, in `ksh` it is _empty_ - any idea why?

Comment: I'm not sure. Your question brings to mind an issue I once discovered (which escapes me now) between how `bash` and `zsh` implement process substitution as well. I think the common thread between the two is that since process substitution isn't defined by a standard, each shell's implementation handles various corner cases differently.

Comment: I noticed that in the man page for the `ksh` that ships with Mac OS X, it explicitly addresses using `<(...)` with input redirection, but is silent about using `>(...)` with `>`. Seems like a suspicious omission...

Comment: Excellent point: it turns out that `ksh` (v93u+) doesn't interpret `>(cat)` as an output  process substitution at all - it treats it as an _output redirection_, but instead of creating a file with literal filename `(cat)`, it creates the following _mangled_ filename: `$'%CA\x{04}'`.

Comment: That's... ugly. I thought there would be some reason why `cat` simply exited early. It's one thing to not support the syntax; quite another not to explain why and/or what happens if you try it.

Answer (score 1):

They are not doing the same job. If you were to take that example:

`ls > grep`

This is taking the output of ls and writing it to a file called grep.

Now if you were to do something like:

`ls | grep '.*.txt'`

This will take the output of ls and grep for any txt files. They in no way provide the same outcome.

Comment: The OP knows that they are not doing the same job - their question is more of a philosophical/architectural nature: why not use a _single construct_ - `>` - in both scenarios?

Comment: Ah i see what you mean.

Comment: I think this answer does address the question:  `> grep` creates a file while `| grep` runs a program.  That is why the same construct can't be used for both.

Comment: @John1024: You have just eloquently _inferred_ that from this answer, but the answer itself doesn't present it that way - it explains the status quo without the rationale behind it. Another way of putting it: Your comment is a superior alternative to the answer.

Comment: @mklement0 Yes, your answer is _more_ explicit.  +1 for it also.